# Octave/GRASS GIS .mat import error: 'map_data' undefined

Tags: arrays, matlab, gis, octave

I have a Matlab script that calculates a certain terrain-parameter (describing the theoretical shelter from and exposure to wind) based on a digital terrain model. The script works both in Matlab and Octave and yields a matrix. 
Now: I am trying to couple this with a GRASS GIS shell script. I can call the script from GRASS, but I have problems getting the output back into GRASS. One way is to use the .mat format. The problem is, however: When I export the result of the calculation (with `save -mat4-binary result.mat ans`) and try to import the .mat file into GRASS, the error is:

> ERROR: No 'map_data' array found in [...file]

Similarly, when I load the file in Octave and try to display it

```
load result.mat 
imagesc(map_data), axis equal, axis tight, colorbar
```

the error is

> error: `map_data' undefined near line 19 column 9
>       error: evaluating argument list element number 1

When I export from Matlab, it is the same problem.

Where is the bug?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bug" is, your mat-file does not contain any variable named "map_data", I would guess your variable in the mat-file is named "ans". I would use `res=load result.mat`, then you get a struct with everything which is in the mat file. If you type in `res.` autocomplete should list all variables inside the struct (not sure about octave), alternatively use `fieldnames(res)` to list all variable names.

/Update:

I took a short look into the documentation of grass. It expects predefined variable names, all beginning with map_*. Instead of

```
save -mat4-binary result.mat ans
```

you should rename your variables to match the documentation and save them using

```
save -mat4-binary result.mat map_*
```

Comment: Daniel, many thanks! 
map_data = ans and then save -mat4-binary result.mat map_data did the trick. The edge/boundaries are missing, so only import into a non-georeferenced map, but that is OK. I can find a work-around in GIS. Thanks again!